# Twitter Bootstrap 3 : Customize column stack order when viewed in Mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a simple bootstrap page using Grid system. I have 3 columns having content `Hello 1`, `Hello 2` and `Hello 3`. When viewed in Desktop all 3 appear as adjacent columns. When viewed in a mobile screen the columns get stacked as `Hello 1` on top, then `Hello 2` and finally `Hello 3`.

I wanted to know how to make `Hello 3` on top, then `Hello 1` and finally `Hello 2`. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahgqqdfb/1/).

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 1
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 2
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 3
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like push and pull makes the job easy. Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahgqqdfb/6/) Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
             <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 3
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 1
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
             <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               Hello 2
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thats the way bootstrap grid system works. There is no any direct way but what you can do is create media queries.

As all the colums becomes float left when you view them in a smaller screen so you can add different classes to each col e.g 
.left_col
.right_col

And in media query float them the way you want.

**Or you can use bootstrap predefined classes : .pull-left or .pull-right**  solution by iJay

Comment: Thanks but I just figured out a way using push and pull.

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant, use float classes. :-) but wait if you use push or pull again your divs will have the same layout as on the larger screen

Comment: So if you want same divs layout then why you need push or pull?

Comment: it's not the same layout .... it's different. Have a look at this in browser https://jsfiddle.net/ahgqqdfb/6/embedded/result/ and then have a mobile view. The stack order is different as I wanted

Comment: Nice! Ok I will edit my answer so that others can get benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do that in pure CSS but you could do it using the library [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). You could hook the media query that yields single column layout and change the order of the columns dynamically.

E.g.:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: your-target-width)", {
    match : function() {
        // sort by 3, 1, 2
    },  
    unmatch : function() {
        // sort by 1, 2, 3
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I just figured out a way using push and pull.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about those classes. +1 to your answer.